# Are engine yards chef recipes just normal chef or is there something custom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, engineyard

Can I use https://github.com/engineyard/ey-cloud-recipes these cookbooks/recipies on my own server or is this specific to the engine yard environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like](https://github.com/engineyard/ey-cloud-recipes/blob/master/cookbooks/solr/recipes/default.rb#L25) they are specifically for the EngineYard environment.

Comment: ok, but I guess they are a great resource to learn and build from then right?

Comment: EY also uses a very old version of Chef. Last I knew it was 0.6.0.2 (.2 being EY's version). The 0.6 release is 2.5 years old; 0.10.4 is the current release, and 0.10.6 will be out soon.